# HttpPostedFileBase null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

HttpPostedFileBase always provides null, I looked online various solutions but the result does not change, I am attaching the code, can you help me?

being that I already have a model in my view I asked myself if it is possible to do this, I do not have to upload more than one file.

ps: I also tried to change the style of the input but it is not changed
I apologize if the English is bad but I have translated with the translator of google

```
 @model WebElementware.Models.TAB_LAVORA_CON_NOI

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "WorkWithUs";
}
<form action="@Url.Action("WorkWithUs","Home")"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@using (Html.BeginForm("WorkWithUs", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { TBLCN = Model, enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<label for="file">Inviaci il tuo curriculum:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
}
</form>
    <section>
        <center>
            <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Cerca!" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </center>
        </section>
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WorkWithUs(TAB_LAVORA_CON_NOI TBLCN ,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string Message = "";
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    TBLCN.LETTO = false;
                    using (DB_WEB_ELEMENTWAREEntities1 DB = new DB_WEB_ELEMENTWAREEntities1())
                    {
                        DB.TAB_LAVORA_CON_NOI.Add(TBLCN);
                        DB.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Message = "Invalid Request";
                }
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = Message;
                return View(TBLCN);       
        }
```

Comment: Why is the submit button outside of the `<form>`? Notice that you are also creating a `<form>` inside another `<form>`

Comment: ok I corrected, but does not change the result , I'm quite novice with the programming and in particular with mvc

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html and not supported

Comment: Model binder is unable to bind the two objects you've posted try to separate those into two separate APIs, I have to mention nested forms are confusing separate those as well.